# How to send image data with HttpSendRequest?

Tags: image, post, wininet

I want to send an image using HttpSendRequest API.

Basically I want to Post the request with some string parameters and after those params I need to send raw image data.

So is it okay to creata a unsigned char buffer of lengh equal to size of strings plus image file size and then doing memcpy of strings and memcpy of image data?

Answer (score 1):

HttpSendRequest can be used to send image data.

Basically we need to open the image data file and read the image file in a buffer and pass that around in HttpSendRequest.

image data should be read in unsigned char buffer.